# Load script in footer of site, only if on specific layout in Hugo?

Tags: javascript, html, hugo

My layout file looks like this:

```
{{ define "main" }}
...
{{ end }}
```

And my `base_of.html` looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ site.LanguageCode | default `en-US` }}">
...
</head>

<body>
    ...

    <!-- cache partial only in production -->
    {{ if hugo.IsProduction }}
    {{ partialCached "script.html" . }}
    {{ partialCached "footer.html" . }}
    {{ else }}
    {{ partial "script.html" . }}
    {{ partial "footer.html" . }}
    {{ end }}
</body>

</html>
```

In the scripts.html file, I load the JS files that *all* pages will use. **However, on a specific layout page, I want to load an additional JS file, but it must be loaded after all of my other site-wide JS files have been loaded.**

From within the scope of the layout page, I do not seem to be able to set a boolean variable that the `scripts.html` partial can reference, so that it knows to load that additional script.

Is there a way to do this with Hugo at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many ways actually.
You could have a front matter "toggle"
i.e. let's say you have a parallax.js you only want to load on certain pages.
In front matter: "parallax: true"
In your baseof you can do:

```
{{ if .Params.parallax }}  
<script html here>
Or via partial (why did you load your scripts via a partial?). 
{{ end }}
```

I don't have access to your repo, so I'm going blind here so:
You could also have that silos layout (i.e. let's say you have /content/about-us/)

And in layouts you put /layout/about-us/

In their have your single and your list files and define your blocks.

See here for examples:

> [templates how to use](https://gohugo.io/templates/base/)
> [single
> page template](https://gohugo.io/templates/single-page-templates/)
> [list page template](https://gohugo.io/templates/views/)

And simply load the scripts you want for that silo.

You could also in your JS simply put an "if" statement to see if a specific class is in that file ( I wouldn't suggest it, but you could ).

So let's say you had a carousel on specific pages and it had a class of "my-excellent-carousel" you then do the if statement in the JS.

That's a few ways.

Let me know if you have any questions.

Also, do look at the Hugo docs.

Specifically: https://gohugo.io/templates/base/
Blocks are good - you might be using them, but I can't tell.

I also always suggest looking at other themes so you can get the "hang" of ways to do this. There are a ton, but you're safe starting with BEP's (being the main maintainer of Hugo) https://github.com/bep/docuapi

Answer (score 1):

### Solution 1: defining another block

One of the possibilities how to achieve this is by specifying another block next to the `main` one in your layout file. You can have as many defined blocks as you want and then you will just render them in other files by the block statement.

```
{{ define "main" }}
    ...
{{ end }}
{{ define "scripts" }}
    <script src="/js/layout.special.js"></script>
{{ end }}
```

Then, in your baseof.html, just add this code after your main scripts to render the block:

```
{{ block "scripts" . }}{{ end }}
```

### Solution 2: conditioning the page type

Another way how to solve this problem is to test the page type using a simple if statement like shown in the code below. This can be done as a sub condition in those conditions you already have in the file, or as a new separate condition after. It depends on your case and goal.

```
<!-- cache partial only in production -->
{{ if hugo.IsProduction }}
    {{ partialCached "script.html" . }}
    {{ partialCached "footer.html" . }}
    {{ if eq .Type "layout-name" }}
        {{ partialCached "script.layout-name.html" . }}
    {{ end }}
{{ else }}
    {{ partial "script.html" . }}
    {{ partial "footer.html" . }}
    {{ if eq .Type "layout-name" }}
        {{ partial "script.layout-name.html" . }}
    {{ end }}
{{ end }}
```

Note that in this case, you must ensure that the page has the type specified. There are two possibilities how to do this:

- use the [predefined page variable](https://gohugo.io/variables/page/) `type` in the front matter in your content files, or
- use the [file-based naming](https://gohugo.io/templates/lookup-order/#examples-layout-lookup-for-regular-pages) where the name of the directory with your layout data will be equal to the string in the condition (in my example, **layout-name**).

The default value of the `.Type` variable is **page**.

Comment: Splendid! And of course it seems obvious now that this would be a way of doing it. Thank you!